# jQuery: Check for next element, if not hide

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some H3 elements that sometimes are followed by a P element.  I would like to check and see if the next element after the h3 is a p, and if not, hide that h3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('h3').each(function(n, e) {
    $(e).next().is('p') || $(e).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('h3').filter(function() { return !$(this).next().is('p') }).hide();
```